# Calling PLSQL stored procedure using string representation of name

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a list of procedures to be called in a given order for all rows in a table. Rather than hardcoding the procedure calls, I would like to add them all to a separate table and loop over the rows containing the procedures calling each one. All procedures requires the same input parameters.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say you have this table:

```
create table procs(procName) as (
    select 'proc1' from dual union all
    select 'proc2' from dual union all
    select 'proc3' from dual 
)
```

and these procedures:

```
create or replace procedure proc1(p1 in varchar2, p2 in number) is begin dbms_output.put_line('running Proc1(' || p1 || ', ' || p2 || ')'); end;
create or replace procedure proc2(p1 in varchar2, p2 in number) is begin dbms_output.put_line('running Proc2(' || p1 || ', ' || p2 || ')'); end;
create or replace procedure proc3(p1 in varchar2, p2 in number) is begin dbms_output.put_line('running Proc3(' || p1 || ', ' || p2 || ')'); end;
```

You may try:

```
declare
    yourParameter1 varchar2(10) := 'X';
    yourParameter2 number       := 10;
begin
    for i in ( select procName from procs order by procName) loop
        execute immediate 'begin ' || i.procName || '(:1, :2); end;' using yourParameter1, yourParameter2;
    end loop;
end;
```

What you get:

```
running Proc1(X, 10)
running Proc2(X, 10)
running Proc3(X, 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a table `procedures_to_run` where column `name` handles names of procedures to be run and `id` that determines order of them. You can call:

```
begin
for x in (select name from procedures_to_run order by id) loop
  execute immediate 'call '|| x.name ||'(INPUT_PARAMS)';
end loop;
end;
```

to get all procedures executed.

Comment: Sorry but what's wrong with the answer that it get downvoted?

Comment: Not using bind variable

Comment: Author said all procedures need the same parameters so hardcoding them won't harm. But yes I agree bind variables make code better here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably overkill in this example, but for this kind of thing you could encapsulate the `execute immediate` inside a type definition, so that the loop can just execute something like `r.task.run();`

Define a 'task' type:

```
create or replace type task as object
( command varchar2(100)
, member procedure run );
/

create or replace type body task
as
    member procedure run
    is
    begin
        execute immediate 'begin ' || self.command || '; end;';
    exception
        when others then
            raise_application_error(-20000, 'Command failed: ' || self.command, true);
    end run;
end;
/
```

Now your table can have a 'task' column instead of a plain string:

```
create table demo_tasks
( created_tate   date default sysdate not null
, last_run_date  date
, succeeded_yn   varchar2(1) check (succeeded_yn in ('Y','N'))
, task           task not null );
```

Some demo procedures:

```
create or replace procedure p1 as begin dbms_output.put_line('This is ' || $$plsql_unit); end;
/
create or replace procedure p2 as begin dbms_output.put_line('This is ' || $$plsql_unit); end;
/
create or replace procedure p3 as begin dbms_output.put_line('This is ' || $$plsql_unit); end;
/

insert into demo_tasks (task) values (task('p1'));
insert into demo_tasks (task) values (task('p2'));
insert into demo_tasks (task) values (task('p3'));
```

Loop through the stored tasks executing each one:

```
begin
    for r in (
        select * from demo_tasks
    )
    loop
        -- Add code here to update run date, status etc
        r.task.run();
    end loop;
end;
/

This is P1
This is P2
This is P3
```

It may not buy you much in this example, but it's worth bearing in mind as an approach.